# How to pull out relationships in nested JS object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, data-manipulation

I have a nested (up to 21 deep) JSON in the following format:

```
{
        "name": "Unknown Wife",
        "id": 341,
        "house": "Tyrell",
        "gender": "Female",
        "partnerId": 340,
        "hasParnter": true,
        "noParent": true,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Olymer",
            "id": 342,
            "house": "Tyrell",
            "gender": "Male",
            "partnerId": 343,
            "hasParnter": true,
            "isSource": true
        }, {
            "name": "Lysa Meadows",
            "id": 343,
            "house": "Tyrell",
            "gender": "Female",
            "partnerId": 342,
            "hasParnter": true,
            "noParent": true,
            "children": [{
                "name": "Raymund",
                "id": 344,
                "house": "Tyrell",
                "gender": "Male",
                "isSource": true
            }, {
                "name": "Rickard",
                "id": 345,
                "house": "Tyrell",
                "gender": "Male",
                "isSource": true
            }, {
                "name": "Megga",
                "id": 346,
                "house": "Tyrell",
                "gender": "Female",
                "isSource": true
            }]
```

I am trying to transform this data into the format

```
{name: "someName", children:["all","children","deeper","in","object"]},
```

So presumably, highest level members of the original object would have the longest array of children. Within a single lineage, this would reduce as you worked deeper down the family tree.

What is the best route for recursively working into the family tree and returning to a new object in the format directly above?

Comment: A better name for that array is `descendants` rather than `children`.

Comment: Should the leafs also have a `children` array, an empty one that is

Comment: Please clarify the output format, would `unknown wife` have olymer, lysa, raymund and rickard all as "children"?

Comment: Sorry yes, so the first level of individuals would potentially have x descendents. Next lowest would include x-(at least)1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Reduce recursively.

```js
var person = {"name":"Unknown Wife","id":341,"house":"Tyrell","gender":"Female","partnerId":340,"hasParnter":true,"noParent":true,"children":[{"name":"Olymer","id":342,"house":"Tyrell","gender":"Male","partnerId":343,"hasParnter":true,"isSource":true},{"name":"Lysa Meadows","id":343,"house":"Tyrell","gender":"Female","partnerId":342,"hasParnter":true,"noParent":true,"children":[{"name":"Raymund","id":344,"house":"Tyrell","gender":"Male","isSource":true},{"name":"Rickard","id":345,"house":"Tyrell","gender":"Male","isSource":true},{"name":"Megga","id":346,"house":"Tyrell","gender":"Female","isSource":true}]}]};
            

function printAll(p1) {
    print(p1);
  if (p1.children) {
    p1.children.forEach(c => printAll(c))
  }
}

function print(p1) {
console.log({person: p1.name, descendents: (p1.children || []).reduce(GetChildren, [])});
}


function GetChildren(children, child) {
  return children.concat(child.name).concat((child.children || []).reduce(GetChildren, []));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="print(person)">Print main person</button>

<button onclick="printAll(person)">Print for all</button>
```

Comment: Interesting - didn't know about reduce. Your example works great. Oddly on my data which I think is identical in form it just returns the first individual.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear to me from your question what's the desired result exactly but it's definitely recursion what you are after, I will assume you want something like this

```js
obj={ "name": "Unknown Wife", "id": 341, "house": "Tyrell", "gender": "Female", "partnerId": 340, "hasParnter": true, "noParent": true, "children": [{ "name": "Olymer", "id": 342, "house": "Tyrell", "gender": "Male", "partnerId": 343, "hasParnter": true, "isSource": true }, { "name": "Lysa Meadows", "id": 343, "house": "Tyrell", "gender": "Female", "partnerId": 342, "hasParnter": true, "noParent": true, "children": [{ "name": "Raymund", "id": 344, "house": "Tyrell", "gender": "Male", "isSource": true }, { "name": "Rickard", "id": 345, "house": "Tyrell", "gender": "Male", "isSource": true }, { "name": "Megga", "id": 346, "house": "Tyrell", "gender": "Female", "isSource": true }] }] }
  results=[]
  children=[]
  function myfunc(myObj){
if(myObj.name){
  myObj.children.forEach(o=>{
    if(!o.children){
      children.push(o)
      results.push({name:myObj.name,children:children})
    }
    else {
      children.push({name:o.name,id:o.id,house:o.house,gender:o.gender,partnerId:o.partnerId,hasParnter:o.hasParnter,noParent:o.noParent})}
  })
    
} 
 if(Array.isArray(myObj.children)){
   for(let i=0; i<myObj.children.length; i++){
    if(!myObj.children[i].children) continue
    if(myObj.children[i].name) results.push({name:myObj.children[i].name,children:[myObj.children[i].children]})
      
      else myfunc(myObj.children[i])
  }
}
  }
  myfunc(obj)
  console.log(results)
```